# Returning lists of pixels connected through their Moore neighborhoods

Tags: image-processing, algorithm

I have a binarized image in Mathematica 9, and I would like to generate a list of coordinates for clusters of pixels connected through their [Moore neighborhoods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood), e.g. $((c_{1,1},c_{1,2},...),(c_{2,1},c_{2,2},...),...)$ where some $c_{n,k}$ is the coordinate for the $k$th pixel in the $N$th set of pixels connected through their Moore neighborhoods.

Is there a simple way to proceed with Mathematica 9's image analysis tool set?

Comment: Have you tried `MorphologicalComponents@Dilation[image, 1]`?

Comment: @belisarius MorphologicalComponents seems to work fairly well, but what exactly is this command doing?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18606/193)? (... and all the answers to that question, BTW)

Answer (score 2):

From Belisarius' comment:

```
MorphologicalComponents@Dilation[image, 1]
```

The documentation states:

> `MorphologicalComponents` assigns sequential integers to different connected components.

and

> `MorphologicalComponents` by default treats all eight pixels surrounding a given pixel as adjacent.

This is precisely the connectedness you were looking for.